# Filtering and Grouping in xslt for xml data

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have an xml content and i am applying xslt 1.0 for transformation on it. I am also passing parameters for filteration. but i am not able to to grouping on filtered data in xslt 1.0.

I will pass "Country Value" (as like 'United States') as parameter for filteration. after filteration, Grouping will be applied on "Group" field for filtered data. and if only one group exist then dont group data. grouping applied only in case if more then one group becomes possible.

please help me on this.

thanks in advance.

Here is my sample XML content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<DataRows>
  -<DataRow>
    - <Country>
      <Conty>United States</Conty>
      <Conty>United Kingdom</Conty>
    </Country>
    <Group>Group 1</Group>
    <Order>1</Order>
    <Name>Name 1_1</Name>
    <Title>Title 1</Title>
    <PhoneNo>732-989-9898</PhoneNo>
    <ImageUrl />
    <EmailId />
  </DataRow>
  -<DataRow>
    - <Country>
      <Conty>United States</Conty>
      <Conty>United Kingdom</Conty>
    </Country>
    <Group>Group 1</Group>
    <Order>2</Order>
    <Name>Name 2_2</Name>
    <Title>Title 2</Title>
    <PhoneNo>732-989-9898</PhoneNo>
    <ImageUrl />
    <EmailId />
  </DataRow>
  -<DataRow>
    - <Country>
      <Conty>United States</Conty>
    </Country>
    <Group>Group 1</Group>
    <Order>1</Order>
    <Name>Name 3_1</Name>
    <Title>Title 3</Title>
    <PhoneNo>732-989-9898</PhoneNo>
    <ImageUrl />
    <EmailId />
  </DataRow>
  -<DataRow>
    - <Country>
      <Conty>United States</Conty>
      <Conty>Germany</Conty>
    </Country>
    <Group>Group 1</Group>
    <Order>2</Order>
    <Name>Name 4_2</Name>
    <Title>Title 4</Title>
    <PhoneNo>732-989-9898</PhoneNo>
    <ImageUrl />
    <EmailId />
  </DataRow>
  -<DataRow>
    - <Country>
      <Conty>United States</Conty>
    </Country>
    <Group>Group 2</Group>
    <Order>4</Order>
    <Name>Name 8_4</Name>
    <Title>Title 8</Title>
    <PhoneNo>732-989-9898</PhoneNo>
    <ImageUrl />
    <EmailId />
  </DataRow>
  -<DataRow>
    - <Country>
      <Conty>United Kingdom</Conty>
    </Country>
    <Group>Group 2</Group>
    <Order>1</Order>
    <Name>Name 9_1</Name>
    <Title>Title 9</Title>
    <PhoneNo>732-989-9898</PhoneNo>
    <ImageUrl />
    <EmailId />
  </DataRow>
  -<DataRow>
    - <Country>
      <Conty>United States</Conty>
      <Conty>Germany</Conty>
    </Country>
    <Group>Group 2</Group>
    <Order>3</Order>
    <Name>Name 5_3</Name>
    <Title>Title 5</Title>
    <PhoneNo>732-989-9898</PhoneNo>
    <ImageUrl />
    <EmailId />
  </DataRow>
  -<DataRow>
    - <Country>
      <Conty>United States</Conty>
      <Conty>Germany</Conty>
    </Country>
    <Group>Group 2</Group>
    <Order>4</Order>
    <Name>Name 6_4</Name>
    <Title>Title 6</Title>
    <PhoneNo>732-989-9898</PhoneNo>
    <ImageUrl />
    <EmailId />
  </DataRow>
  -<DataRow>
    - <Country>
      <Conty>United States</Conty>
    </Country>
    <Group>Group 2</Group>
    <Order>3</Order>
    <Name>Name 7_3</Name>
    <Title>Title 7</Title>
    <PhoneNo>732-989-9898</PhoneNo>
    <ImageUrl />
    <EmailId />
  </DataRow>
  -<DataRow>
    - <Country>
      <Conty>Germany</Conty>
    </Country>
    <Group>Group 1</Group>
    <Order>1</Order>
    <Name>Name 10_1</Name>
    <Title>Title 10</Title>
    <PhoneNo>732-989-9898</PhoneNo>
    <ImageUrl />
    <EmailId />
  </DataRow>
</DataRows>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really wanted to do filtering first, then grouping, then you are looking at some sort of 'two pass' transform. This can be achieved by use of the node-set extension function, to create a result-tree fragment which contains the filtered data.

In the following example, I am using Microsoft's extension function, but depending on your platform, you may have to specify another. ( EXSLT is another common one. Use name space http://exslt.org/common for that. )

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:param name="Conty">United Kingdom</xsl:param>

   <xsl:variable name="FilteredData">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/DataRows/DataRow" mode="filter"/>
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:template match="DataRow" mode="filter">
      <!-- Check this DataRow matches the filter -->
      <xsl:if test="Country[Conty=$Conty]">
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="filter"/>
         </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Ignore Country node in the filter -->
   <xsl:template match="Country" mode="filter"/>

   <!-- Identity template for filter -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="filter">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="filter"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="/DataRows">
      <xsl:copy>
         <!-- Read the filtered data -->
         <xsl:choose>
            <!-- Check there is a Group which differs from the first group -->
            <xsl:when test="msxsl:node-set($FilteredData)/DataRow[position() > 1][Group != msxsl:node-set($FilteredData)/DataRow[1]/Group]">
               <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($FilteredData)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($FilteredData)" mode="nogroup"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Filtered data row -->
   <xsl:template match="DataRow">
      <!-- Is this DataRow the first in the group -->
      <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::DataRow[Group=current()/Group])"><!-- If so, create the group node -->
         <Group>
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
               <xsl:value-of select="Group"/>
            </xsl:attribute><!-- Get all the DataRow elements from the filter for the current group -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../DataRow[Group=current()/Group]" mode="ingroup"/>
         </Group>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Identity template for the group -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="ingroup">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="ingroup"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Ignore Group and Country node in the grouping -->
   <xsl:template match="Group|Country" mode="ingroup"/>

   <!-- Identity template for no grouping -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="nogroup">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="nogroup"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is used, the output should be as follows

```
<DataRows>
    <Group name="Group 1">
        <DataRow>
            <Order>1</Order>
            <Name>Name 1_1</Name>
            <Title>Title 1</Title>
            <PhoneNo>732-989-9898</PhoneNo>
            <ImageUrl/>
            <EmailId/>
        </DataRow>
        <DataRow>
            <Order>2</Order>
            <Name>Name 2_2</Name>
            <Title>Title 2</Title>
            <PhoneNo>732-989-9898</PhoneNo>
            <ImageUrl/>
            <EmailId/>
        </DataRow>
    </Group>
    <Group name="Group 2">
        <DataRow>
            <Order>1</Order>
            <Name>Name 9_1</Name>
            <Title>Title 9</Title>
            <PhoneNo>732-989-9898</PhoneNo>
            <ImageUrl/>
            <EmailId/>
        </DataRow>
    </Group>
</DataRows>
```

See [Understanding the node-set function](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html) for more information.

Comment: This is perfectly good Tim. You are great. one final thing i want to ask, is it possible that i can get number of groups going to be possible after filteration, so if only one group will be possible then i will not group it and if more then one group is possible then group it. Thanks a lot for your help Tim.

Comment: I have amended it so that if there is only one group, then no grouping is done.

Comment: Sorry Tim, but there are few corrections in updated xslt. for "<xsl:when test="msxsl:node-set($FilteredData)/DataRow[position() > 1][Group != msxsl:node-set($FilteredData)/DataRow[1]/Group]"> " condition is reverse and need to mention mode there,

Comment: "<xsl:when test="msxsl:node-set($FilteredData)/DataRow[position() > 1][Group != msxsl:node-set($FilteredData)/DataRow[1]/Group]">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($FilteredData)" mode="nogroup"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($FilteredData)" mode="ingroup" />
        </xsl:otherwise>" and in case of grouping it shows group name for each datarow. which i tried but didnt get success. Tim are you using any XSLT builder tool which allows auto matically building up xslt?

Comment: Hello again. It still appears to work for me. It might be easier if you amend your original question to show your expected XML in the case where is grouping, and another example for when there is only one group and so no grouping.

Comment: Hi Tim. Whatever was the case, but Whatever changes i explained above, works for me with little bit twist. so cheers..Thanks a lot for your time and great help..I guess i need to learn xslt a lot..by the way, can you tell me any tool you know about which allows to design xslt visually like sharepoint designer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you did a two-phase transform, I think you should probably do the grouping first, and then the filtering.

Grouping would be achieved by the common Meunchain Grouping method. You first define a key to look up **DataRow** elements based on their **Group**

```
<xsl:key name="RowLookup" match="DataRow" use="Group"/>
```

And then, to get the unique group names, you match the DataRow elements which happen to be the first occuring element in your key for their particular group

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="DataRow[generate-id() = generate-id(key('RowLookup', Group)[1])]"/>
```

So, now you have grouped by the **Group** elements, so you need to check there it at least one DataRow element for the current group that matches the filter

```
<xsl:if test="../DataRow[Group=current()/Group]/Country[Conty=$Conty]">
```

And then to get all DataRow elements for the current group, you could use the key

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('RowLookup', Group)" mode="ingroup"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:param name="Conty">United Kingdom</xsl:param>

   <xsl:key name="RowLookup" match="DataRow" use="Group"/>

   <xsl:template match="/DataRows">
      <xsl:copy>
         <!-- Select unique groups -->
         <xsl:apply-templates 
            select="DataRow[generate-id() = generate-id(key('RowLookup', Group)[1])]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="DataRow">
      <!-- Check any DataRow elements for the current group match the filter -->
      <xsl:if test="../DataRow[Group=current()/Group]/Country[Conty=$Conty]">
         <Group>
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
               <xsl:value-of select="Group"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <!-- Get all the DataRow elements for the current group -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('RowLookup', Group)" mode="ingroup"/>
         </Group>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="DataRow" mode="ingroup">
      <!-- Check this DataRow matches the filter -->
      <xsl:if test="Country[Conty=$Conty]">
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
         </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Ignore Group and Country elements -->
   <xsl:template match="Group|Country"/>

   <!-- Standard Identity Transform for all other nodes -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When you apply this XSLT to your sample XML, you get the following results

```
<DataRows>
   <Group name="Group 1">
      <DataRow>
         <Order>1</Order>
         <Name>Name 1_1</Name>
         <Title>Title 1</Title>
         <PhoneNo>732-989-9898</PhoneNo>
         <ImageUrl/>
         <EmailId/>
      </DataRow>
      <DataRow>
         <Order>2</Order>
         <Name>Name 2_2</Name>
         <Title>Title 2</Title>
         <PhoneNo>732-989-9898</PhoneNo>
         <ImageUrl/>
         <EmailId/>
      </DataRow>
   </Group>
   <Group name="Group 2">
      <DataRow>
         <Order>1</Order>
         <Name>Name 9_1</Name>
         <Title>Title 9</Title>
         <PhoneNo>732-989-9898</PhoneNo>
         <ImageUrl/>
         <EmailId/>
      </DataRow>
   </Group>
</DataRows>
```

I am not sure if this is the exact structure you want, but I hope it gives you the general idea.

Comment: Thank you so much Tim for your reply and take a time to look into this issue.

Comment: sorry to say but whatever xslt you provide me is not working. if you can give me some kind solution which first do filteration and then grouping then it will be great but if not possible and you will give me solution which will do grouping first and then filteratin that would also be great.

Comment: It works for me! Can you be a bit more precise as to what is happening for you when you try it? Do you get an error? Is the output XML not as expected? If you could provide a sample of the output you are expecting, that would help alot.

Comment: Sorry Tim, It was my bad, your xslt part is working fine. Actually i have some other stuff also with whatever you gave me and i was doing a small mistake while integrating your xslt with my xslt with some mosification. but then i keep your part intact and adjust my xslt a little bit and its working. but still i was trying to do filter first and then grouping and if only one group is there then dont group items. if i pass filter value and based on it if only one group is possible then not group items. is it possible? thanks a lot again for all you time and effort.